# Is not length contraction a distortion of light?

Tags: special-relativity

[image: dsfa]
[image]

The first picture shows how length contraction occurs.
The second picture is based on the first picture, showing that the light in front of the bar reaches the observer slower than the light in the back.

Isn't the length shrinking because the light from the front of the bar reaches the observer slower than the light from the back of the bar?

Comment: You should explain your diagrams

Comment: @AaronStevens it has been modified. look again.